# [unit testing]: how can I get updated props after a click event that has a mock axios call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, jest-mock-axios

**Code**

```
let basicProps = {
  inCart: false,
  quantity: 0,
  min: 1,
  max: 10,
  productData: mockProductData
};

const mockData = {
  inCart: true,
  quantity: 1,
  min: 1
};

const mockOnAddToCart = jest.fn(async (data, props) => {
  const newProps = await mockAxios(data).post()
  const updatedProps = { ...props, newProps };
  return updatedProps; 
});

test('if clicking the "ADD" button, renders the "increment" button',() => {
  let newProps;
  async function onClickEvent () {
    newProps = await mockOnAddToCart();
  };

  const { getByText, rerender } = render(
    <CTAWrapper 
      {...basicProps}
      onAddToCart={onClickEvent}
    />
  );  

  // CLICK ADD BUTTON
  fireEvent.click(getByText('Add'));
  console.log({...newProps});     // log - {}


  // RE-RENDER PRODUCT CARD COUNTER
  // rerender(<CTAWrapper {...newProps}/>);

  // TEST IF THE INCREMENT BUTTON IS THERE
  // expect(getByText('+')).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

__mocks__/axios.js

```
export default function(data) {
  return {
    get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(data)),
    post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(data))
  };
}
```

**Problem**

This code doesn't seem to work properly. AFAIK, it is because when I fire the onClick event, it runs `onClickEvent` asynchronously, which updates the value of `newProps` after it's being logged to the console. The value of `newProps` is needed to re-render the component for further assertion testing.

**Objective**

- Want to mock the `onclick` function
- The `onclick` function should make a *mock* `axios` call
- The `axios` call should return a promise
- The resolved value of that promise should be the data that is passed to the *mock* `axios` function
- The component should re-render with new props

**Stack**

- [jest](https://github.com/facebook/jest)
- [@testing-library/react](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library)
- [jest-dom](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom)

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: when you run `fireEvent` wrapper updates on its own. You don't need to re-render that manually. check [their examples](https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/blob/master/examples/__tests__/input-event.js). So if it does not work to you probably something is wrong with component or axios mock.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see the code for your components. Judging by your test the problem is that the logic to update `CTAWrapper` lives in its parent component. If you render that component after the asynchronous code is executed the DOM should update accordingly.

Comment: On the contrary, the logic is in this component itself. Sending the request to update the value from this component and then receiving the props from the parent component(redux setup)

Comment: But are you rendering the `Provider` with your store?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. Do you mean `Provider` as in the Parent Component, `Provider` as `CTAWrapper` component or `Provider` as the Context Provider?
I am maintaining a redux state, the functions are all helpers, no direct methods are passed from the Parent to the `CTAWrapper` component